# NetSuite Suitlet

Tags: javascript, netsuite

What I want to do:

I have employees entity/record in my netsuite with their supervisor field. I want to create a feature where a particular user has rights to change the supervisors of employees in bulk means the user can select the employees and select the supervisor and on button click it will the change the supervisor of all the selected employees

What I have done uptill now:

I have created a suitlet. In that I have created a form. On form I have added a project dropdown and sublist. What I want is that when user select the project all the employees of that project will get loaded in the sublist and after that I will submit the form and it will change the supervisor of all the employees in the sublist.

Please suggest how to approach this in netsuite.

Comment: I am using suitescript version 1

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't need to script this at all. You can instead use a Mass Update.

In the Classic Center:

1. *Lists* > *Mass Update* > *Mass Updates*
2. *General Updates* > *Employee*
3. Name your new Mass Update, perhaps "Change Supervisor"
4. Build the search criteria that will generate the list of Employees that need to be updated
5. On the *Mass Update Fields* tab, select *Supervisor* and choose which Employee will be the new Supervisor
6. Click *Preview*
7. Check the resulting Employees that you would like to update; uncheck any you don't
8. Click *Perform Update*

Comment: I surely try this out. Thanks for suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

simple, you can use mass updates!!!!!!!
Its simple and no code is needed.
happy coding

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution. Please [EDIT](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5419867/edit) to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead